# Autocomplete git in mac OS not working?

Tags: git, macos, bash, terminal

I am using git in mac. I am trying to have the autocomplete feature. I followed these steps (http://www.codethatmatters.com/2010/01/git-autocomplete-in-mac-os-x/) but I get this error, any idea?

: command not found
-bash: /Users/me/git-completion.bash: line 80: syntax error near unex'ected token `in
-bash: /Users/me/git-completion.bash: line 80:`case "$COMP_WORDBREAK'" in

Comment: Seems like a problem with COMP_WORDBREAK: http://groups.google.com/group/gnu.bash.bug/browse_thread/thread/f2b8376986e65b16

Comment: That's about a segfault; I'm pretty sure that Julio is having a different problem.

Comment: I'd recommend tagging this `bash` instead of `terminal`, by the way.

Comment: The `case` statement from that script works fine for me in Bash 2.05, 3.2 and 4.0 on a Linux system. There's either something that's OS X specific or there's some other part of the script that's causing this misleading error message or the file is corrupted (or there's something wrong with your Bash executable). It seems odd that the error message says "unex'ected" instead of "unexpected". Can you edit your question and post the complete error messages (part of it seems to be missing) and lines 79-84 of the script? In the mean time, you might try re-downloading the script in case it's corrupt.

Comment: It works for me on Snow Leopard (10.6) which includes "GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)"  Did you really run curl -O or did you try to copy-paste the text into TextEdit?

Comment: Accepted answer did not work for me. I have found a blog post which is explaining step by step what to do. http://code-worrier.com/blog/autocomplete-git/ - After installing git-competition, you should force bash to execute this script otherwise it is useless.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had tried to use curl -O but the url was wrong and I ended up copying the text which caused the error.

Using this command made it work perfectly:

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
```

Thanks a lot everyone for your help!

Comment: This will get the latest version, not the correct version for the git you have installed. Here's code that will get the correct version, and install it: `eval "$(curl -s https://gist.github.com/raw/972430/install-git-completion.sh)"`. More at http://johnfgibb.com/how-to-install-git-autocompletion

Comment: The updated link is https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash - the code in John's gist didn't work for me though: `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '<'`

Comment: This works: eval `$(curl -s  https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash)`

Comment: Github changed their urls – anyone trying to use my previous snippet should now use: eval "$(curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/johngibb/972430/raw/install-git-completion.sh)"

Answer (score 3):

The git-completion.bash distributed is a Windows file with "\n\r" as a newline.  You need to remove the '\r'.

For vim users, just do ":set ff=unix".

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! Also learned a new vim command.

Answer (score 2):

Was getting .git-completion.bash: bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory in Mountain Lion.

Should be "source ~/.git-completion.bash" in ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody's answering, quick sanity check: What does `bash --version` say?  OS X tends to ship slightly outdated bashes, so if your system is old, it might be a compatibility thing.  I'd expect that Bash 3.x works fine, but with 2.x I'm not so sure.

Comment: GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Answer (score 1):

From your error report:

```
case "$COMP_WORDBREAK'" in
                     ^ the problem is in unpaired apostrophe
```

Answer (score 1):

save the file e.g. in gedit with Linux Line-Ending